# Unexpected result of git rebase master in local branch

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I had a local branch which was branched off master quite some time ago, on which there were several commits. I wanted to get this local branch up to date with master so I did

```
git co my_branch
git rebase master
```

expecting this to replay the commits in my_branch on top of master. However, it seems to have instead merged the commits in my_branch into master and then brought my_branch forward to the same place as master, i.e. I've gone from this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D master, origin/master
      \
       E -- F my_branch
```

to this:

```
A -- B -- E -- F -- C -- D master, origin/master, my_branch
```

when I was expecting this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D master
                \
                 E' -- F' my_branch
```

My question is not so much why it did this, but whether I can put things back to where they were originally, since presumably the inserted commits will be problematic when interacting with the remote repository (to which subsequent commits have been pushed).

**Edit**

It turns out that I had already merged in the branch. So, the rebase had nothing to do and just left the my_branch pointer in same place as master.

Comment: That command would not modify the master branch in any way (as it was not checked-out), can you verify that it did actually modify master's history?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall The commits from the branch appear in the log for master. Perhaps they got there some other way though - previously I had been trying to cherry-pick a commit from master, which I decided to give up on. I suspect my clumsy attempts to reset the state at that point may have caused a problem.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall You're perfectly right. The changes are from when the branch was merged in to master at an earlier date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my edit above, it turns out I had already merged in my_branch. So, the branch commits were already part of master, and the rebase had nothing to do after moving the my_branch pointer to the last commit in master.